# Positioning Div One Third of the Viewport Height

Tags: css, positioning

Yo, I'm trying to make my site look swag by using the rule of thirds.

I've got a div of stuff that is fairly tall that I want to position 1/3rd of the distance of the viewport height from the top of the browser window.

So this is what I feel like I should be doing but it's not working:

```
div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 33vh; /* maybe margin-top: 33%; but that seemed to be worse */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50rem;
  transform: translate(0, -50%); /* To compensate for the divs own height */

  position: relative; /* Not relavent to this situation but might be causing problems? */
}
```

I think specifically the

```
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

isn't working right.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need, the best solution is going to be  through using JavaScript.

For the JavaScript part, you'll want to do something like the following:

```
<script>
var vHeight = window.innerHeight; // get viewport height value
var vHeight3rd = vHeight/3; // get a 3rd of the viewport height value
$('div').css({position: 'absolute', marginTop: -(vHeight3rd)}); // assign a negative top margin of the 1/3rd value to position

// add for when resizing browser, value will be adjusted accordingly.
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    var vHeight = window.innerHeight; // get viewport height value
    var vHeight3rd = vHeight/3; // get a 3rd of the viewport height value
    $('div').css({position: 'absolute', marginTop: -(vHeight3rd)}); // assign a negative top margin of the 1/3rd value to position
});
</script>
```

I've not tested the above solution. But it should work the way you need it to. And my solution is using jQuery, so make sure to add the library to your solution.